# problem when I combine multiple queries with the Boolean Query of Lucene.net (version 2.9)

Tags: search, lucene.net, lucene

I am getting the problem when I combine multiple queries with the Boolean Query of `Lucene.net` (version 2.9).

Please see the document structure which I indexed.

```
ID  Make      Model     Price   MakeDate    CreatedBy
1   Ford      Fiesta    240000  06/23/2011  anil
2   Ford      Focus     250000  06/20/2011  anil
3   Vauxhall  Astra     200000  06/21/2011  anil
4   Ford      Focus LX  230000  06/21/2011  anilkumar
5   Ford      Focus XI  260000  06/20/2011  anil
```

My intention is to get the records which are contains `focus` in any of field ie Model or Make,.. fields and `CreatedBy` equals to `Anil`.

For this I written the following queries.

```
WildcardQuery query4 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("Make", "*focus*"));
WildcardQuery query5 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("Model", "*focus*"));

var queryParser3 = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, "CreatedBy", analyzer1);
var query3 = queryParser3.Parse("anil");

objBool.Add(query3, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
objBool.Add(query4, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
objBool.Add(query5, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

When I execute this, Actually I need to get only two records ie 2nd and 5th.  But I am getting four records ie other than 4th.

As per my understanding its returning the all the records which are `CreatedBy` equals to `Anil`.

Please suggest me how to get the required result and what are the changes need to be done.

Comment: For scoreless searching, there's no reason to have MUST and SHOULD clauses of the same BooleanQuery. If a document MUST include 'cat', and SHOULD include 'dog', the SHOULD clause is superfluous because you'll just get all documents with 'cat', whether they contain 'dog' or not. If, though, our query does do scoring, then we might include a SHOULD clause with a MUST clause if we boost the SHOULD clause. So we could search for all documents that MUST have 'cat' but score boost those documents that also happen to also have 'dog'.

Answer (score 3):

You need to nest your queries, it makes more sense if you write your statement in pseudo-code with some brackets, what you're actually trying to do is:

```
CreatedBy=='anil' AND (make~='*focus*' OR mode~='*focus*')
```

What you need to do in your code is add an additional step in to nest the 2 SHOULD queries in a MUST query.

E.g:

```
objBool.Add(query3, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
objBool.Add(query4, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
objBool.Add(query5, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

would become:

```
objBool.Add(query3, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

BooleanQuery nested = new BooleanQuery();
nested.Add(query4, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
nested.Add(query5, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

objBool.Add(nested, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

The other thing to consider, is that Lucene is not a database, it's perfectly valid to create a column called `MakeModel` when you index the content which contains both the make and model, this will then make for simpler and faster queries. With Lucene constructing your index is just as important, if not more important, than constructing the query.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  Yes its works for me and got the idea on how to use multiple conditions on multiple fields. Thanks once again...

Answer (score 0):

queryParser.Parse("+Model:focus +CreatedBy:anil")

Comment: This will work when we check strickly with Model field and CreatedBy.  But i want to apply contains for Model and Make fields and Equal to CreatedBy field.  Just like (Model='*focus*' OR Make='*focus*') And CreatedBy='Anil' .